# Problems using anonymous function in matlab

Tags: matlab

For function like

```
fun = @(x,y) x+y
```

Can I annotate x to 1 and generate the function equals to `@(y) 1+y`? Is there anyway to do that without creating a new function?

I am asking this question because I can't modify the function with part of the fixed value and apply it to functions like `arrayfun`

Comment: you would need to create a new function. But that can reuse this fun.

Comment: `fun1 = @(y)fun(1,y)`

Comment: Why not just use fun(1, y)?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you mean by "do that without creating a new function" since the first part of the question asks about how to "generate" a new function.  You have basically three choices, depending on what you wanted:

1. Just call `fun(1,y)` where you need the value.
2. Define another anonymous function `g = @(y) fun(1,y)`.
3. Use the direct definition `h = @(y) 1 + y`.

Comment: probably just a typo, but in your third option don't you mean `h = @(y) 1+y` (_without the extra_ `=` _character_)

Comment: How can I put it in arrayfun?